# How to get orderid after completing payment through PayPal Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway

I have integrated PayPal Smart payment buttons in my website. My site is built in PHP codeigniter framework.
i want to know whether I can get the orderid after successful transaction.`

```
<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '0.01'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }
```

add `console.log(details);` in here

The *orderid* is of no real practical value after capture, however. It is for the payment approval/capture process only, and afterward has absolutely no accounting value.

A resulting payment id from the capture is what corresponds to a PayPal transaction.